# Blogger URL PARAMETER javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, blogger

I need some extra URL parameter to add in my blog and it post. 
If I like to keep `?id=100` or `?id=parameter` after all original link

Like if some of visit my blog.

```
www.example.com/?id=parameter
example.blogspot.com/?id=parameter
```

If someone Open blogger Post

```
www.example.com/link-of-blogger-post.html?id=parameter
example.blogspot.com/link-of-blogger-post.html?id=parameter
```

If some of Open pages.

```
www.example.com/p/link-of-blogger-page.html?id=parameter
example.blogspot.com/p/link-of-blogger-page.html?id=parameter
```

Hope you understand, i just like to keep some extra `?id=anything` after all original link.

Please tell me the javascript which redirect to `?something=something` after original link.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href = url` ist the JavaScript code to make a redirect.  `url` has to be a string. [Here is a JsFiddle exmaple.](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/vhueydjn/3/)

EDIT: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/vhueydjn/4/) is the new fiddle.

Tested with:

- www.example.com/path/index.html?id=parameter?test=test
- www.example.com/path/index.html
- www.example.com/?id=parameter?test=test
- www.example.com/?id=parameter
- www.example.com/
- www.example.com

EDIT #2:
Bug Fix: Old version did not consider a protocol in the input-url, but `window.location.toString()` gets the url with protocol....

-> [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/vhueydjn/5/)

Comment: Your code is correct, but blogger structure is different.